# Creating a link in javascript/jquery by using github api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, github-api

In my commits table it shows the sha, author, message, and the date of the commit I made for a specific Github repo. How can I make the message column a clickable link to the GutHub page that shows what I did for that commit

The code is under `\\Repos`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoRbPP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your codepen to have the link you are asking for:

`var messageTd = $("<td>").append('<a target="_blank" href="' + commitData.html_url + '">' + commitData.commit.message + '</a>');`

View it here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obNKZQ

Comment: Thanks a lot you're a life saver!